# Timeslot availability multiple days mysql

Tags: mysql, calendar

I have a question regarding free time slot retrieval in MySQL.I have 2 tables.

```
 Table 1:
 TimeSlots (Defines the available timeslots in 15 minutes)

 Columns : StartTime (**Time**), EndTime(**Time**)
 Data:

 00:00:00 , 00:15:00
 00:15:00 , 00:30:00
 And so on until 23:45:00 , 00:00:00
```

Table 2 Scheduler (Holds the scheduled tasks)

```
 Columns : idScheduler (**pk**) , Room (**int, fk**), StartDateTime (**DateTime**), EndDateTime (**DateTime**)
```

The query I use in order to retrieve the open timeslots for a day is:

```
     SELECT StartTime, EndTime FROM TimeSlots WHERE 
     NOT Exists (                
            SELECT Room, StartDateTime, EndDateTime FROM Scheduler
        WHERE Room = 'Room1'
        AND DATE(StartDateTime) =  '2012-12-20'
        AND 
            (StartDateTime >= concat('2012-12-20', ' ' ,StartTime) AND
            StartDateTime <= concat('2012-12-20', ' ' ,EndTime))
            OR
            (EndDateTime >= concat('2012-12-20', ' ' ,StartTime) AND
            EndDateTime <= concat('2012-12-20', ' ' ,EndTime))
            OR
            (EndDateTime <= concat('2012-12-20', ' ' ,StartTime) AND
            StartDateTime >= concat('2012-12-20', ' ' ,EndTime))
        )
```

Room and StartDateTime will become paramaters in the final solution.

The problem I have that if a room is booked for example that spans multiple timeslots
(Example : 1, 1, 2012-12-20 13:10:00, 2012-12-20 13:55:00)

If I run the query mentioned above it will give this output:

```
13:00:00 - 13:15:00
13:15:00 - 13:30:00
13:30:00 - 13:45:00
13:45:00 - 14:00:00
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT StartTime, EndTime FROM TimeSlots WHERE 
 NOT Exists (                
        SELECT Room, StartDateTime, EndDateTime FROM Scheduler
    WHERE Room = 'Room1'
    AND DATE(StartDateTime) =  '2012-12-20'
    AND 
        (StartDateTime <= concat('2012-12-20', ' ' ,EndTime) AND
        EndDateTime >= concat('2012-12-20', ' ' ,StartTime))
    )
```

In this way you're asking for a timeslot that is not intersected by any room booking.

Comment: It works, but I don't completely get what you are saying, could you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Sure, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. A room booking between RoomStart and RoomEnd (I'm using these names for clarity) occupies a timeslot SlotStart-SlotEnd if (and only if) the booking starts before the slot's end AND ends before the slot's start, which is to say RoomStart <= SlotEnd AND RoomEnd >= SlotStart). To check this is true, you could try and visualize all the different possibilities. So in your query you select the slots for which an intersecting booking doesn't exist. Hope this is a bit clearer.